# In TYPO3 8.7 composer install installs typo3 and index.php as a directory and file instead of as symlinks

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-8.x, ddev

#### Problem

In TYPO3 8.7 `composer install` installs `typo3` and `index.php` as a directory and file instead of as symlinks.

#### Background

- I wanted to regenerate my vendor directory so did `rm -rf vendor/ public/typo3conf/ext/*` from a MINGW64 console with Admin privs on my host machine followed by `composer install` also from the host, not the container.
- I am using DDEV for a local testing environment (which explains why I'm mentioning host/container).
- My host machine is Windows 10 Pro.
- I'm not using `typo3/cms` but instead requiring every individual package needed like `typo3/cms-core`, `typo3-cms-blahblah`.

I found the only way I could fix the problem last time was to wipe the entire project and recreate it and this just isn't the right solution.

Comment: This is all done in a Windows host environment, true? Doesn't have anything to do with ddev really? If that's the case, please remove the ddev tag.

Comment: @rfay I removed DDEV as a tag, sorry about that. DDEV is still relevant to the description of what I'm doing but isn't specifically the cause of the trouble. As you mentioned Windows does a horrible job with symlinks and it's caused us a lot of issues. I'm still stuck on this one still though.

Comment: Thanks, just trying to keep the ddev list as clean as possible. Please try doing the same thing you're doing with a plain vanilla TYPO3 composer build and see what your results are. If that works, then there's something different between it and your setup. Also, try to nail it all on one simple environment (and doing it inside the web container is a good place because it's linux, with less confusing things)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is expected behavior...** there is a supposed to be a difference when switching from `typo3/cms` to explicitly requiring the packages via `typo3/cms-*`. *(Based on a reply from @Matthias Brodala via the #typo3-cms-composer channel in slack).*

#### When using `typo3/cms` package

From your webroot...

- `index.php` (symlinks to `../vendor/typo3/cms/index.php`)
- `typo3` (symlinks to `../vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/`)

#### When using `typo3/cms-*` packages

From your webroot...

- `index.php` (not a symlink)
- `typo3` (not a symlink)